# Using Easy Google Fonts correctly and Droid Sans on Max OS X

Tags: css

I have Easy Google Fonts working along with my API key entered. However, it doesn't seem to be working.

There is no fallback in my font list and I following settings the font to display in Customise-Typography

```
font-family: 'Droid Sans';
```

Here is what I have it set to:

http://postimg.org/image/mhi6m81y3/

Also when my menu was set to Bold for Droid Sans, Mac OS X would not display it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your CSS put the `font-family` inside your `body { }` tag and then it should work.

```
body {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
}
```

Also I recommend setting a fallback font for the reason listed in [W3C Schools CSS Web Safe Fonts](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp)

Best of luck :)

Comment: You mean add body {font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;} in the Add CSS Selectors?? Any idea why when set to Bold it won't show properly in Mac OSX?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not to sure what you're trying to achieve I just thought your font on your Web Page wasn't showing the font that you wanted

Comment: Inside the css Selector if you input body and hit enter it will select the body of the Website so that means all the text inside the Website will change to that font. Then to give it a Bold look you just need to add font-weight: bold; You've put 400 and that is just under the normal font-weight.

Comment: It is showing, but without any fallback options, as above. So no arial, sans-serif etc. I also added a, ul, li and * as it wan't working for those properties after setting in Customiser. Some of the site displayed in new font, other parts didn't.

Comment: That's because you haven't given it any fall back options, you need to do what I did above `font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;` that will give it  fallback option if you do `font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;` in the CSS Selector then it will give it a fallback option